# Exit to command line in Python

Tags: python, command-line, scripting, exit, execfile

I have a script that I want to exit early under some condition:

```
if not "id" in dir():
     print "id not set, cannot continue"
     # exit here!
# otherwise continue with the rest of the script...
print "alright..."
[ more code ]
```

I run this script using `execfile("foo.py")` from the Python interactive prompt and I would like the script to exit going back to interactive interpreter. How do I do this? If I use `sys.exit()`, the Python interpreter exits completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code block in a method and return from that method, like such:

```
def do_the_thing():
    if not "id" in dir():
         print "id not set, cannot continue"
         return
         # exit here!
    # otherwise continue with the rest of the script...
    print "alright..."
    # [ more code ]

# Call the method
do_the_thing()
```

Also, unless there is a good reason to use execfile(), this method should probably be put in a module, where it can be called from another Python script by importing it:

```
import mymodule
mymodule.do_the_thing()
```

Comment: Even easier would be to invert the if-condition and execute the rest of the script only if this condition is fulfilled. I just thought there might be a simpler way to stop the execution of the script. But apparently there is not :)

Comment: Actually, it *is* a good idea to make sure your preconditions are met at the beginning of a method. So checking first and only continuing if all conditions are correct is a good approach.

Answer (score 7):

In the interactive interpreter; catch `SystemExit` raised by `sys.exit` and ignore it:

```
try:
    execfile("mymodule.py")
except SystemExit:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little obsessed with ipython for interactive work but check out the tutorial on [shell embedding](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/rel-0.10/html/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython) for a more robust solution than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587114)  (which is your most direct route).

Comment: I know I'm two years too late to this party, But is there an updated link?

Comment: Shell embedding is sustained by the ipython project. The latest one is here: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13.1/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython.

Comment: Man!!!! I've been searching for this for sooooooo long! Thanks a lot! Making it easier for the lazy ones: import ipython `from IPython import embed` and then use embed() in the place you want to stop execution and go for interactive work
`embed() # this call anywhere in your program will start IPython`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using execfile, you should make the script importable (**name**=='**main** protection, seperated into functions, etc.), and then call the functions from the interpreter.